# Weird network disconnects on some clients

Tags: windows, networking, router

## Network situation

Router: Mikrotik

Switch in between router and end user
Server directly attached to Mikrotik router.

End users work on a laptop and have a USB dock connected to the laptop, although we also tested with a network cable directly into the laptop, but I mention it to be thorough.

The server runs Windows Server 2019 with only the Hyper-V role installed. It hosts a guest: Windows Server 2019 with domain controller role and File Print server role installed.

DHCP and DNS are handled by the Mikrotik.

## The problem

There are 10 clients (windows 10) connected to the network, not all powered on at the same time.
3 of the clients experience frequent disconnects on the network. When a network disconnect happens the following two eventlogs are found on a client (translated from dutch to english):

```
Network connected
Name: ############.local
Description: ##########.local
Type: Managed
Status: Disconnected
Category: Domain Verified

[Machine Name: ######.#######.local] [Username: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE]
```

```
Network Connected
Name: Identifying...
Description: Identifying...
Type: Unmanaged
Status: Connected
Category: Public

[Machine Name: ######.#######.local] [Username: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE]
```

The disconnects do not happen at the same time.

Sometimes it is like 5 minutes in between, other times it can be good for a few hours.

Rebooting the server often seems to make the problem go away for a while.

What we already did
We tried a lot, so forgive me if I forgot to mention one of the things we did...
We replaced the switch, the network card in the server, firmware update on the router, one of the computers was replaced for a new one with new windows installation and it happens to that laptop too.

On the server, we ran the following powershell command: `Disable-NetAdapterRsc -Name "Ethernet"` We tried other commands too, but that has been several weeks ago. Can't find the commands in my log anymore.

If the user is outside of the network and uses VPN to connect to the server, they do not seem to experience any issues.

When a user experience issues, it can be that their network interface resets 3 times in 1,5 hours and then not at all for 2 more hours.

We tried focussing on one client (the one with the new laptop) and checked event logs around disconnects, but aside from the disconnect itself, there is no apparent reason why its happening.

The Mikrotik logs show no reset on its side, and nothing in the log at the time of a disconnect either.

Comment: Can you try the following:  (1) Router firmware upgrade and (2) Substitute a different router to test.

Comment: Ah, good one. We did do a firmware update on the router already. I'll write down testing with a different router, though the weird thing is, a server reboot usually fixes it for a while and not all clients experience issues. I've setup monitoring to give me eventlogs 10000 and 10001 so its no longer a : user comes to me, type of identification, but actual monitoring to know when a client is having issues, and it does not generate issues for all clients.

Comment: maybe it is possible to use wireshark (or other tool) on one of the affected computers to analyze the packet flow just before and around disconnect